# Transform basic geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js

I am trying to recreate [this Three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_minecraft_ao). It's generating terrain geometry from a set of predefined block faces. However, simply copying the code over to start with, I ran into an issue.

Here is the code for one block face from the example:

```
var pxGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );

pxGeometry.faces[ 0 ].vertexColors = [ light, shadow, light ];
pxGeometry.faces[ 1 ].vertexColors = [ shadow, shadow, light ];
pxGeometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ].y = 0.5;
pxGeometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 2 ].y = 0.5;
pxGeometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ].y = 0.5;
pxGeometry.rotateY( Math.PI / 2 );
pxGeometry.translate( 50, 0, 0 );
```

This throws `pxGeometry.rotateY is not a function`.

As far as I can tell, rotate and translate functions are not available on `PlaneGeometry` by default. However, I cannot see where these are added in the example, if that is the case.

How do you rotate, translate, and scale basic geometries in Three.js?

Comment: the example you reference does use r74.

Comment: @gaitat I updated the question. I just directly copied code and added latest cdn so I assumed that must've been the problem. That said, I still can't find the problem.

Comment: so then the problem is not in the code you posted. here is fiddle with your code using r74 with no errors: http://jsfiddle.net/8fhxw4je/

Comment: Turns out the "quick add" menu for codepen adds r70, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of `THREE.PlaneGeometry` is built on top of the `THREE.Geometry` prototype. You can see that [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js#L23). This means all methods of [`THREE.Geometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Geometry.js) are also available in a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` instance.

`THREE.Geometry` has a `rotateY` method. You can see that [here in the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Geometry.rotateY) and [here in the file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Geometry.js#L112).

So to answer your question: you can use all methods from `THREE.Geometry` to rotate, translate, and scale your basic geometries.